# problem with natbib

Tags: natbib

I'm writng an article but `natbib` does not recognize my citations.

I have followed this process for the compilation :

1. pdfLatex
2. Bibtex
3. pdfLatex
4. pdfLatex

Also, I have tried to remove the `.aux` and `.bbl` files,
but I have observed no change.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}


\begin{document}
the text beginning \citep{Benezit2013}  the end of the text

\bibliography{bibliov2}
\end{document}
```

And, I think my file.bib is correct:

```
@phdthesis{Benezit2013,
  author = {Benezit, M},
  pages={76},
  school={Ecole d'Agronomie Superieure Montpellier},
  title={{Diagnostic agronomique des facteurs limitants du rendement du  pois protagineux d'hiver et de printemps en Champagne Berrichonne}},
  type={Master's thesis},
  year={2013}
}
```

this is an extract of my file.log

```
  No file testv4.bbl.
  Package natbib Warning: There were undefined citations.
  LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/ua1/m/sl' in size <10> not available
  (Font)              Font shape `T1/ua1/m/it' tried instead on input line 28.
  LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `T1/ua1/m/it' will be
  (Font)              scaled to size 9.49997pt on input line 28.
  [1{C:/Users/stagex5/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}
```

I thank for your support in advance

Comment: What does the `.blg` file say?

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise on *how* exactly things don't work for you? You might want to check the `.blg` and `.log` files (the `.blg` being more interesting probably). See also [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864). On first glance your code seems fine, so the problem is likely somewhere else. Is your `.bib` file called `bibliov2.bib` and resides in the same directory as your `.tex` file?

Comment: I make a mistake when i was writing the post, but any .blg file are generate in the case of this script

Comment: thanks for your answer the bib  and tex file are in the same directory,

Comment: Sorry, are you saying there is no `.blg` file? If you don't get any you either didn't run BibTeX or something went seriously wrong when you tried to.

Comment: yes, you can see on the file. extract about the file.blg

Comment: @lou -- you say in your question that the excerpt you show is from the `file.log` (i assume that's `testv4.log`).  the `.log` file is not the same as the `.blg` file.  the `.blg` file is the log from the bibtex run, and it looks quite different from what you show.  look again for that file, and it should tell you what the problem is.

Comment: okay i understand. i have used the same bibtex for 2 differents tex files. for just one, there is a .blg file. The problem come from the bibtex. natbib did not recognize a { . I have just remove and replace it , and all have worked. May be, this error come from the export from Mendeley. thank to everyone for your quick message